# How can I separate each item from a franchise pack or bundle if I gifted it to myself?

Tags: steam

Just brought Metro Franchise Pack, which includes

- Metro 2023
- Metro Last Light
- Metro Last Light RPK DLC
- Metro Last Light RANGER DLC

They all come as 1 item in my inventory since I bought it as a gift. I only want metro 2023 and I want to give Last Light and the DLC to my friend. Is this possible?

Comment: If they came together as a single item, I'm afraid not.

Answer (score 10):

Most bundles on Steam come all as one and individual games cannot be separated. There are some exceptions, though, [explained here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4502-TPJL-2656):

> Extra copies will only be issued as a special promotion in the
>   following specific cases:
>
> - Users who own "Left 4 Dead" and then go on to purchase "Left 4 Dead + Left 4 Dead 2 Bundle" will receive an extra copy of "Left 4 Dead"
> - Users who own “Half-Life 2” and go on to purchase “The Orange Box” or the "Valve Complete Pack" will receive an extra copy of “Half-Life
>     2”.
> - Users who own “Half-Life 2: Episode One” and then go on to purchase the "Half-Life 2: Episode Pack”, “Valve Complete Pack” or “The Orange
>     Box” will receive an extra copy of “Half-Life 2: Episode One”.
> - Users who own "Dawn of War II"and then go on to purchase "Dawn of War II Gold Edition" will receive an extra copy of "Dawn of War II"
> - Users who purchase the available four packs for specific Steam titles will receive three extra copies of that title to gift to
>     friends.
> - Extra copies may apply as a part of some limited time promotions. In that case, information on what will be included with your purchase
>     will be listed on the storefront's transaction page.
>
> These special promotions will allow you to send a gift pass for your
>   extra copy to a friend who does not already own the game.
>
> These promotion do not apply to any games other than those
>   specifically listed.
>
> #### Limitations
>
> “Half-Life 2” and “Half-Life 2: Episode One” are only eligible to
>   receive extra copies once.
>
> For example, if you own “Half-Life 2” and/or ”Half-Life 2: Episode
>   One” and receive extra copies for your purchase of “The Orange Box”,
>   you will not receive additional extra copies if you then go on to
>   purchase the “Valve Complete Pack”.

Comment: _(and I'm totally clueless about why on Earth would they decide to go with such a complex plan)_

Answer (score 5):

If you bought the items as a bundle, it cannot be separated.  When you redeem it, all items are immediately credited to the account that redeemed.