# Can I purchase a game bundle as a gift even though I have already purchased it?

Tags: steam

I've purchased the Portal bundle (http://store.steampowered.com/sub/7932/) and I'm considering buying a second copy of it as a gift, since it's on a 75% sale right now.

Will it be possible to purchase and gift the bundle to a single individual? If so, will I have to pay the amount I would pay if I bought Portal and Portal 2 separately, since I have already purchased the pack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy an app (game or software) as a gift whether or not you own it. You can also buy a sub (bundle) as a gift even if you have none, some, or all of the apps in it.

Just add it to your cart...
[image: Add to cart]

Then select *Purchase as a gift*
[image: Purchase as a gift]

Then select the method you wish to send or store your gift, either *Email my gift*, *Send my gift directly through Steam*, or *Store the gift in my inventory to send later*
[image: Email my gift | Send my gift directly through Steam | Store the gift in my inventory to send later]

Then just check out and you'll have bought a gift copy of a bundle you already have the games for. That's why it's called a gift. Note that you *can not* separate the games contained in the bundle to gift them to different users, or use part of the bundle yourself. Bundles are ([nearly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/160350/57720)) always all-or-nothing.

Comment: I just wanna add that I had bought a bundle and already had 2 of the games in it. Those 2 extra copies ended up in my inventory that I could gift away.

Comment: @user1337 Click the link that says "nearly" at the bottom of my post and read what is says.

Comment: I already own the Portal Bundle.  I'm attempting to buy a copy of it again to gift to a friend, but the "Add to Cart" button is grayed out.  When I hover my mouse over it, it says that "This bundle is not available for purchase on your account since you already have all included items".  What do I do?

Comment: @Doc Multi-pack bundles include 1 license for you + the other licenses as inventory copies. If you already own the game, you can't buy the multi-pack. You could try having a friend buy it, you pay the friend, and the friend gives you the extra copies.

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be incorrect. I have the Just Cause 3 XXL bundle and the "add to cart" button is grayed out and inactive. There appears to be no workaround but I could still purchase everything as an individual item and forego the bundle savings.

Comment: Yes, that kind of bundle was introduced only after this question was asked. In fact, the "bundle" mentioned in the question doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to purchase the bundle as a gift.

I tested by adding a bundle I already own to my cart. When you view the shopping cart, there will be a bright orange notice under the bundle name stating: **"You already own everything in this package"**. The button to purchase for yourself reflects this (it's grayed out) but the button to purchase it as a gift is still available. The price is also that of the bundle and not the separate amounts added together.